# Selecting everything but Specific item in string

Tags: c#

*Please excuse if the title is vague*

I have a string like this: `var curStr = "39bta,1q7l,vlaya,zkfaa,bc[ke],cc[b7ic,h7ko,c4ic]";`
What I need to do is select all of the ID's, **except** for the ones directly behind a `[` (So not `bc` or `cc`)

I have attempted this issue with the following:

```
var initSplit = curStr.Split('[');
var count = initSplit.Count();
List<String> z = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    var y = initSplit[i].Split(',');
    var i1 = i;
    var t = y.Where(x => x != initSplit[i1].Split(',').Last()).ToList();
    z.AddRange(t.Select(u => u.Replace("]", String.Empty)));
}

var stringArray = String.Join(",", z.ToArray());
```

Which works exactly how I want it to, *and puts it in a CSL*, however it's ignoring the last item (`c4ic` - Probably because of the .Last() part). Is there any cleaner or more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: "Directly *behind* a `[`"... did you mean directly in front of (before) a `[`?

Comment: Before - So `bc` is before the `[`, and it wont get selected.

Comment: Do you mean it's ignoring `c4ic` instead of `c41c`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, will change that

Comment: The problem is that when you do `Last()` then on the first set because `initSplit[i]` ended with the outer one you want to skip the last gets rid of it. The last item in `initSplit` actually ends with an item you want to keep so the last is wrong. You can "quick fix" it by putting a comma on the end of your string which would make the last item in `y` an empty string and then when you do `Last` it would ignore it. This is just how to fix your code though rather than necessarily the best way to do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Church of one line:

```
var x = curStr
         .Split(',')
         .Select(y => y.Contains('[') ? y.Split('[').Skip(1).First() : y )
         .Select(z => z.Replace("]",string.Empty));
```

Comment: That's smart.  Better than my regex version.

Comment: this will fail if a part contains more than  one `[`

Comment: @Selman22 - I can think of many inputs that would cause this to fail.  I can only write to the requirements given.

Comment: Nice. Clean and simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
// If you don't need ] let's remove it first and split on comma
var parts =  curStr.Replace("]","").Split(',');

// get the parts that contains [, 
// split them and get only those parts that comes after [
// by checking the index
var p2 = parts
        .Where(x => x.Contains("["))
        .SelectMany(x => x.Split('[').Where((a, idx) => idx % 2 != 0));

// concat them into one list
var result = parts.Where(x => !x.Contains('[')).Concat(p2).ToList();
```

This won't handle cases like `bc[[`, you can use `x.Split(new [] { '[' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` to handle those cases as well.

[`Fiddle`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ovUd9y)

Comment: Two things - you are redefining x in an inner lambda causing compile problems (I note you've fixed it in your fiddle but not the code here). Also its worth noting that this does not preserve order which may or may not be important (the original sample does but it isn't stated as a requirement).

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is pulling the inner items out.  if you slit on commas you'll have items like `cc[b7ic`.  Then you can just use a Regex to get rid of the front part:

```
var items = curStr
            .Split(',')
            .Select(item => Regex.Replace(item, @"[^\[]*\[(.*)", "$1").Replace("]", ""));

var result = string.Join(",",items);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this  regular expression:

```
string pattern = @"\,([a-z]*)\[";
string replacement = ",";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace(curStr, replacement);
result = result.Replace("]","");
string[] array_result = result.Split(',');
```